# Flutter- How to draw Image from camera/gallery on canvas?

Tags: flutter, drawimage

I am learning flutter and came across with drawing image from gallery/camera on canvas using CustomPainter. My code is drawing image , but for some reason it is just showing a small part of whole image(not the complete picture) on the  screen.

**_loadAssetAsImage** is being called in **initState()** function where key is the actual path of the image.

```
void _loadImage( String key ) async {
var data = await rootBundle.load( key );
var codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
codec.getNextFrame().then((info){
  setState(() {
    isImageloaded = true;
    image = info.image;
  });
});
  }
```

Once **setState** is called, than **_buildImage()** get called which is in the **build()** function

```
Widget _buildImage() {
if (this.isImageloaded) {
  return new CustomPaint(
      painter: new ImageEditor(image: image),
  );
} else {
  return new Center(child: new Text('loading'));
}
  }
```

Here **ImageEditor** is the custom class extending **CustomPainter**

```
class ImageEditor extends CustomPainter {
  ui.Image image;
  ImageEditor({this.image});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawImage(image, new Offset(0.0, 0.0),new Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Everything looks right to me in here, but not able to understand why only a very small part of Image gets shown on the whole screen instead of full picture.
Please help me if anyone has a good suggestion on whats missing in the code.
[image]

**This is what I expected**

[image]
**This is what I am getting**

Comment: tried to call `print(image)` inside `paint` method? what do you see then?

Comment: also, post a screenshot with a checked `Debug Paint` as [here](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/android-studio#debugging-visual-layout-issues)

Comment: @pskink - print(image) gives me **[2268×4032]**

Comment: Can you illustrate an example for this?

Comment: ok now call `print(size)` inside `paint` method - what do you see now?

Comment: I did it , instead of painting it straight on canvas, i made a paint paint function  and passed rect and box fir along with image and canvas and instead using **canvas.drawImage** , I used **canvas.drawImageRect**.

Comment: what do you see now if you call `print('size: $size, image: $image')`?

Comment: This is what I did to make it work
    @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        Rect myRect = Offset(0.0, 0.0) & Size(width, height);
        drawImage(image, myRect, canvas, new Paint(), BoxFit.contain);
      }

Comment: void drawImage(ui.Image image, Rect outputRect, Canvas canvas, Paint paint, BoxFit fit) {
    final Size imageSize = Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
    final FittedSizes sizes = applyBoxFit(fit, imageSize, outputRect.size);
    final Rect inputSubrect = Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.source, Offset.zero & imageSize);
    final Rect outputSubrect = Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.destination, outputRect);
    canvas.drawImageRect(image, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, paint);
  }

Comment: could you answer? what do you see now if you call `print('size: $size, image: $image')`?

Comment: I see 
**Size(0.0, 0.0), image: [2268×4032]**

Comment: so your `CustomPaint` has size of **0px x 0px**, the docs say: *"Custom painters normally size themselves to their child. If they do not have a child, they attempt to size themselves to the size, which defaults to Size.zero. size must not be null."*, more [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)

Comment: and when you fix `CustomPaint` size problem simply use [paintImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/paintImage.html) function in your `ImageEditor#paint` method

Answer (score -1):

The reason why the canvas only displays a small portion of the image is because the image that's being displayed wasn't scaled down to fit on the widget. What you can do here is scale the image size when painted on the canvas.

```dart
class ImageEditor extends CustomPainter {

  ...

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    paintImage(
        canvas: canvas,
        rect: Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight),
        image: image,
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
  }
}
```